# How to use UPDATE with SELECT, GROUP, HAVING?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this select command

```
select emp_code, time_date, time_remarks, sum(Tot_hrs) as vTotalHrs 
FROM c04 
WHERE co_code='APPLE'
    and time_date>='01-APR-2020' 
group by emp_code, time_date, time_remarks 
having sum(Tot_hrs)>24
```

With this select command the Time_remarks is NULL. I would like to update Time_Remarks to a particular value. How can I do that? I tried using

```
UPDATE c04 set TIME_REMARKS = '24more' (//above select command)
```

but it just updated the entire table. Could someone tell me where I went wrong

Comment: `I would like to update Time_Remarks to a particular value` ← Which rows do you want to update? Only where the value is currently `null`? Or where it is null for the returned values in the `where` clause? Or something else?

Comment: @Igor Where it is null for the returned values in the where clause

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming that your emp_code is a unique ID:

```
UPDATE    c04
SET       '24more' = time_remarks
WHERE     emp_code IN (select    emp_code
                       FROM      c04 
                       WHERE     co_code='APPLE'
                             and time_date>='01-APR-2020'
                             AND time_remarks IS NULL
                       group by  emp_code, 
                                 time_date, 
                                 time_remarks 
                       having    sum(Tot_hrs)>24)
```

Comment: I want to update the whole table itself with time_Remarks as '24more' and not just display using select

Comment: Hi @AedenThomas, I made edits to my query by allowing the '24mote' to update only the rows that have time_remarks as NULL by capturing only the emp_code (assuming it is a unique ID), otherwise, you may want to include a unique ID and replace emp_code fields in the WHERE and SELECT and GROUP BY clauses with the unique ID field.  Does that help at all?